# Research Questions / Hypotheses for an Engineering (CS) Thesis

Tags: phd, research-process, thesis, writing, computer-science

I am writing a PhD proposal on a solution to an AI problem that hasn't been solved before (although there's related research). I am having trouble determining what kind of research questions / hypotheses are appropriate for this topic. I can't propose my solution is better, faster, more efficient than some previous technique (as is common in CS theses) as there is nothing to compare it to, it's a novel problem. I am not testing a hypothesis as to how something works (such as a theory of evolution, or quantum mechanics), nor developing some set of equations to describe some phenomenon. Rather I am using some standard machine learning algorithms to solve the problem. What form then should my hypotheses take? That I solve the problem to within some degree of accuracy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Formal hypotheses are over-rated, but still often necessary for scientific communication, especially for a pedagogical exercise like a thesis proposal.  The key question here is this: how will you know if you have succeeded in your intended work?

If the problem hasn't been solved before, then your core hypothesis is that it *can* be solved effectively with your proposed approach.  From that spills out a whole bunch of secondary questions:

- Is the problem well-defined enough that "solved" is meaningful? This is often especially problematic in AI (e.g., "human-like behavior in a chat-bot", "good book recommendations")
- Relatedly, how can you measure whether you have actually solved the problem?
- What is the difference between a trivial/toy solution and an effective solution?  Again, a big problem in AI, where it's often possible to make systems that technically solve the problem but practically do not (e.g., for real applications they require unavailable curated data, or a thousand years of training time).
- What sort of "partial solution" milestones are there along the way that will help you tell whether you are on the right track?
- What would an optimal solution be?  Can it even be identified?
- What will you learn if your chosen approach doesn't seem to be working?  Will it be possible to definitively tell that it *cannot* be a solution?
- How will you know when you have done enough?

If you can provide good answers to all of these questions (or even just most of them), then you will have a very solid thesis proposal, built around the hypothesis of "Approach X can solve Problem Y."